# Detecting possible Photoshoped/Modified image using metadata. Python

Tags: python, image, image-processing, graphics, metadata

I'm currently viewing http://imageedited.com/ website which does exactly what i want in the free version.

Does someone know how to do it, or is Open Source Software available for half of what it has.

To tell if an image is photoshopped or edited. There are three categories of techniques. Metadata, Metadata Validity, and Pixel level. Our image edited tool checks only basic metadata.

```
import PIL.Image
import exifread

img = PIL.Image.open('hashed image/POST_F240445_23_21_R.jpg')
exif_data = img._getexif()
f = open('hashed image/POST_F240445_23_21_R.jpg', 'rb')
tags = exifread.process_file(f)

print exif_data, tags
```

> Output: {274: 1} {'Image Orientation': (0x0112) Short=Horizontal (normal) @ 18}

I'm trying to extract information, which device the photo was possibly taken from.

Comment: @Piinthesky updated it pls let me know if its still wrong

Comment: Try `exiftool image.jpg` or `jhead -v image.jpg` or `identify -verbose image.jpg`

Comment: but i want to use Python Only